# Why isn't it undefined behavior to use ptr::read() on a dropped Box?

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior

I was testing some of Rust's unsafe functionality, mostly the `std::ptr` functions, to see the ways I could cause undefined behavior (just out of curiosity). In the example below I use `std::ptr::read()` to move the address stored in `x` into `y` without uninitializing `x`.

After the read I thought I had two pointers to the same location on the heap. I was under the impression that when I left the block where `x` is defined that `x`'s destructor would be run causing `y` to point to freed memory. However, when I go and print the value of `*y`, it still prints the correct value of 10. I read the documentation but can't seem to figure out why this isn't UB. If anyone could clarify this for me, I would really appreciate.

PS. I come from a C background, so an explanation with respect to C might make it a tad easier to understand what is actually going on.

```
fn main() {
    let mut y: Box<i32>;

    {
        let x: Box<i32> = Box::new(10 as i32);
        unsafe {
            y = ptr::read(&x);
        }
    }
    // I thought the destructor (free) would be called here on x
    // making y point to invalid memory
    // However, the following call to println! still works
    println!("The value of y is {}", *y);
}
```

Comment: I would say it is undefined behaviour.. because, [it doesn't work on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=955afc169e787677819339fc14c853a9&version=stable&backtrace=0). Also, changing between Debug and Release also changes the output on the playground. Even more interestingly, [printing it within the unsafe block makes it work on the playground consistently](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=89a044547d99d2cc93bbc179302ff8ba&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: Well isn't that odd? I was using the playground last night and it wouldn't crash but now it does. Thanks for the comment Simon.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what browser do you use with the playground? I feel like I am getting odd behavior using Firefox.

Comment: I used Chrome. More weight added to the undefined behaviour conclusion :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Undefined Behavior" includes "it appears to work correctly". The worst mistake you can make when it comes to Undefined Behavior is interpreting a correct result as an absence of Undefined Behavior.

It *doesn't* work for me, by the way (and the value changes on every run).

```
$ cargo run
     Running `target/debug/so-ub`
The value of y is -500126584
```

Comment: Thank you very much Francis! I was pretty sure it was undefined behavior (definitely would be in C) but given my inexperience with Rust I just wanted to double check.